# (unexpected EOF while looking for matching) Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am getting a strange error while  archiving my project. `'Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2'` I have tried alot of ways to fix this have seen alot of posts on this but that all didn't work for me.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMYWO.png) is the error I am getting.

Comment: are you  running a shell script?

Comment: What is `\`123.build`? It seems to complaining about that loose `\`` character, because it is being treated as a special character.

Comment: @SurajSukale iam running project on xcode while archiving am getting this error

Comment: @TomLord yes but am not getting where is it exactly.

Comment: Search the relevant part of your file system/code base for `123`.

Comment: Yes i searched in my machine i found that file too but when am archiving it ...compiler is automatically creating some files inside that folder..@TomLord